# What to do when regular approaches fail on linear, non-homogeneous ODES.

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems

In my research problem, I have come across the following form of a time varying, non-homogeneous ordinary differential equation.

$$\dot x + \frac{k_1}{t} x = k_2t^{3n}\sin(bt) + k_3 t^n \sin(bt) - k_4 t^{3n} \cos(bt) + k_5 t^{n} \cos(bt)$$ where the $k_i$'s are constants.

I found in a book by Henry D'Angelo that as long as the time-varying coefficient is continuous (which it is in the interval that I'm examining said system), a solution exists for this system.

I used Mathematica to compute an analytical solution which it does fairly rapidly but the solution involves incomplete gamma functions. If the second term didn't exist i.e. $\frac{k_1}{t} x$, then I can see where the incomplete gamma integral might come from.

I do not, however understand how Mathematica constructed the analytical solution. I have tested the analytical result versus numerical results and they seem to behave identically which tests the validity of the analytical result (am I wrong in assuming this?).

If anyone can share some input on how one goes about attempting to generate solutions for such a system, I'd be much in gratitude as one can't use traditional approaches to determine $x(t)$. In fact, any reference/discussion at all would be excellent, too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Call your RHS $g(t)$, so we have:

$$\dot x + \frac{k_1}{t} x = g(t),$$

which is a 1st order linear ODE. This can be solved introducing an integrating factor such that:

$$ \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t} \left(I x\right) = I g. $$

You can check that we obtain $I = \exp{(\int k_1/t \, \mathrm{d}t)} = t^{k_1}$. Then, integrating once you will find the solution for $x$ in the form:

> $$\color{blue}{x(t) = A \, t^{-k_1}  + t^{-k_1} \int t^{k_1} g(t) \, \mathrm{d} t , \quad A \in \mathbb{R}}$$

The gamma function appears when integrating terms of the form $t^\alpha \sin{ \beta t}$ (or $\cos{\beta t}$), but I guess that you were interested just in the general procedure to obtain $x(t)$.

Hope this helps!

Cheers.

Comment: Thanks! That's extremely helpful. I just made some minor edits to my question as well as your answer:

1.replacing $x'$ with $\dot x$

2. $x$ with $t$ in the derivative in the second equation in your answer.

Comment: Happy to help, @gadha007. Consider accepting the answer or tell me if you need more help for solving the problem.

Comment: Will do, @Dmoreno. That looks great, actually. A little annoyed at myself for missing that. Just to give you some background on what I was trying to do: the ode above is actually an approximate linearization of a nonlinear one. When I plugged the linearized ODE into Mathematica, the symbolic solution was extremely long. Further, when I specified the system's physical parameters, the solution to the above ODE is complex with really,really small imaginary parts to the solution; not sure why they appear but they might be numerical/precision errors from all the irrational numbers in the solutions.

Comment: Could you go over my corrections to ensure they are okay, @Dmoreno?

Comment: Hi again! I'm using my phone right now, so I cannot stay here for much time, but the edits seem OK to me. I'm quite interested in your original ODE, please write it down in your post if it's not a problem . Let me know about your progress!

Comment: Hey. So, it is difficult to paste the original model in here because of several reasons, but in essence it is just the Euler rigid body equations of motion modified for a mass varying system. In fact, the above equation that I typed lacks a couple more terms in it. And has been heavily simplified.

Comment: I'm now having trouble with having mathematica do the integration in the RHS of the last equation. Can't really figure out why. Even solving it as an ODE in your penultimate equation doesn't work: the integral just evaluates to zero. But thanks for your insight, @Dmoreno. It was really helpful.